# Using trigger with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger, dynamic-content

I'm dynamically loading content which includes a series of buttons. I want to trigger a click on a second button when the first button is pressed, however the trigger event never fires.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', '.main-button', function() {
    var self = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $('button.' + self + '.product-id').trigger('click');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-1 main-button"></button>
    <button class="b-1 product-id"></button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-2 main-button"></button>
    <button class="b-2 product-id"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery's `trigger` only works if you trigger the event on the element it was originally bound to, and it works with event handlers added by jQuery. If you're trying to trigger a native click, try `$('button.'+self+'.product-id').get(0).click()`

Comment: Working on a solution... but before that a quick comment: your `.main-button` class on your HTML is wrong, type it as `main-button`, otherwise you have to reference it as `..main-button` and that makes no sense (similarly for product-id by the way)

Comment: @AGE Yup, that wasn't part of the actual code, I typed it incorrectly. Will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the dot in the actual class name, only in the css selector. Instead of `class="b-1 .main-button"` you want: `class="b-1 main-button"`. The same for the other classes.

Note: you also have to have an onclick handler for the product buttons, otherwise you won't see the clicking.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.main-button', function() {
    var self = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    $('button.' + self + '.product-id').trigger('click');
});

$(document).on('click', '.product-id', function() {
  var klass = $(this).attr('class');
  alert(klass + " prod button triggered");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-1 main-button">B1 main</button>
    <button class="b-1 product-id">B1 prod</button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-2 main-button">B2 main</button>
    <button class="b-2 product-id">B2 prod</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the answer closest to the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret your question is:

1. When I click on `.b-1` a click on `.b-2` will occur.
2. The click from the first button is associated with the click of the second button by the class name, meaning `.b-1.main-button` to `.b-2.main-button` and `.b-1.product-id` to `.b-2.product-id` respectively.

**NOTE**: Your code has a mistake in which you have incorrectly labeled your classes in your HTML. Therefore change:

```
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-1 .main-button"></button>
    <button class="b-1 .product-id"></button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-2 .main-button"></button>
    <button class="b-2 .product-id"></button>
</div>
```

Into the following:

```
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-1 main-button"></button>
    <button class="b-1 product-id"></button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-2 main-button"></button>
    <button class="b-2 product-id"></button>
</div>
```

Now into the JQuery that handles the **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**. This is pretty straight forward. When you click on a button, trigger a click event on another button:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Trigger click when clicking on respective b-1 button
  $(".b-1.main-button").click(function(){
    $(".b-2.main-button").trigger("click");
  });
  $(".b-1.product-id").click(function(){
    $(".b-2.product-id").trigger("click");
  });
  // Show an alert to identify which click was triggered
  $(".b-2.main-button").click(function(){
    alert("Main Button 2");
  });
  $(".b-2.product-id").click(function(){
    alert("Product Button 2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-1 main-button">Main Button 1</button>
    <button class="b-1 product-id">Product Id 1</button>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button class="b-2 main-button">Main Button 2</button>
    <button class="b-2 product-id">Product Id 2</button>
</div>
```

If I have interpreted your question correctly then you should have a solution based on the above. Any questions you have, please ask in the comments below.

Comment: The jQuery wouldn't work as you've presented it here at the HTML is dynamically loaded, which is why I'm using `$(document).on('click', ...)` to select the click events.

Comment: @Ryan that is something I did not consider but thankfully it is a simple enough change, I am glad you found the answer you where looking for